# Is a django template forloop resetabble?

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

Is it possible to reset the forloop.counter object back to zero?

I'm using it to spit out objects, but when the object type changes I want to zero it, so that I can count to 5 objects and output an end of row object (with no right padding) as the fifth and only fifth object in that type.

And if I've got 5 objects, the first two are type a and the next 3 are type b, the fifth one will always get the smaller padding, never mind that its only the third on the line.

Here is my template code:

```
{% for project in projects %}
    {% ifchanged project.proj_type %}
        {% forloop.counter=="1" %}
        </div>
        <div class="span-4 prepend-top">
            <h5 class="right" >{{ project.proj_type }}</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="span-19 append-1 last" id="row-of-projects">
    {% endifchanged %}

    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"4" %}                    
        <div class="span-4 append-1 prepend-top last" id="project">
    {% else %}
        <div class="span-4 append-1 prepend-top" id="project">
    {% endif %}
        <p class="project-name">{{ project.name }}</p>                    
        <a href="/gallery/{{ project.slug }}/" ><img src="/media/pa/photographs/{{ project.get_photograph }}-t.jpg" alt="{{ project.name }}" /></a>
        </div id="project">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: should add the forloo.counter==1 shouldnt be in there, it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure that I understand what you need.

You can use the `regroup` tag to display your objects according to type.

And you can use `class="{% cycle 'normal' 'normal' 'normal' 'normal' 'special' %}"` to style every fifth element differently.

Comment: that would also fix my issue. thanks for pointing it out. i read about it in the official documentation, but couldnt understand how it'd help. your quick example was perfect.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you should be [regrouping](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) objects based on type, and doing the padding in the inner loop.